# Is it necessarily bad style to ignore the return value of a method

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a C# method

```
public void CheckXYZ(int xyz) {
  // do some operation with side effects
}
```

Elsewhere in the same class is another method

```
public int GetCheckedXYZ(int xyz) {
  int abc;
  // functionally equivalent operation to CheckXYZ, 
  // with additional side effect of assigning a value to abc
  return abc; // this value is calculated during the check above
}
```

Is it necessarily bad style to refactor this by removing the `CheckXYZ` method, and replacing all existing `CheckXYZ()` calls with `GetCheckedXYZ()`, ignoring the return value? The returned type isn't `IDisposable` in this case. Does it come down to discretion?

EDIT: After all the responses, I've expanded the example a little. (Yes, I realise it's now got `out` in it, it's especially for @Steven)

```
public void EnsureXYZ(int xyz) {
  if (!cache.ContainsKey(xyz))
    cache.Add(xyz, random.Next());
}
```

```
public int AlwaysGetXYZ(int xyz) {
  int abc;
  if (!cache.TryGetValue(xyz, out abc))
  {
    abc = random.Next();
    cache.Add(xyz, abc);
  }
  return abc;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It entirely depends upon what that return value is telling you and if that is important to know or not. If the data returned by the method is not relevant to the code that is calling it then ignoring it is entirely valid. But if it indicates some failure/counter/influential value then ignore it at your peril.

Comment: Then why do you call a method if the result is not relevant? Still, +1 for "ignore at your peril"

Comment: It depends what the method is doing really, and under certain circumstances you might not be interested in the return value, depending upon what it represents. In theory of course, if a method has a return value you should always check it, but that isn't to say that the method was coded correctly in the first place.

Comment: +1. "Then why do you call a method if the result is not relevant?" - there are many examples where it's not relevant - for example IList.Add returns the index of the added item, which you may or may not be interested in.  Surely any developer should be able to tell from the context whether or not it's appropriate to ignore a return value?

Comment: @dbemerlin, the return value of the method might be irrelevant to some callers, but in all cases the result (mutation of this object's state) is definitely relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Usually it's bad style, yes. It's allowed and ok where methods return an instance of the class for chaining (foo.bar().baz().xyz().asdf() => asdf returns the instance foo but you don't need it anymore)

In your case the point of bad style wouldn't be the ignored return value but the methods with side effects. A CheckXyz() function should *always* return a boolean and have no further side effects.

In general, side effects are bad and if you call a method and can ignore the returned value it means that the method/object/library/program might be poorly designed.

Comment: I probably used the term side-effect too loosely, and the method should probably be named <code>EnsureXYZ</code>, as it's purpose is to mutate the state of the object on which it's called into a usable state.

Comment: Then you are using two different objects, one UnusableThing and a UsableThing and the function should be public UsableThing TransformToUsableThing() { if (this.Validate()) return new UsableThing(this.Foo, this.Bar); throw new UnusableThingException(); }.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it's generally best to have one (and only one) way of doing things to avoid duplicating your codebase. Generally though, if you sometimes use and sometimes don't use the return value, it's probably a sign that your code could be broken down in a better way. In your example, it would probably be fine if both of those functions called a third (common) function to avoid duplicating the core functionality.

Error codes should always be checked for and handled but if the function's just returning information then what you do with that information is up to you.

**[Edit]** ...and as dbemerlin points out, side effects should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: Essentially, that's what I'm trying to do: removing the duplicate ways of doing things when they offer no additional value.

Answer (score 3):

A common C convention is to write this:

```
(void)GetCheckedXYZ();
```

The cast to void has no effect, but by convention it shows that the developer knows that the return value is being ignored, i.e. it shows it's deliberate.

C# won't let you do that, but I've seen this instead (Also in Java):

```
/*(void)*/GetCheckedXYZ();
```

Which some may feel lacks aesthetics, but it does convey the intent of the developer without resorting to alternative versions of methods, which to my eye seems worse.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these answers have good points.  I'd just add that if you choose to ignore a return value, then comment it along the lines of "don't care about the return value because...", so that the next person who comes into the code will see that you have not missed it by accident and that you have thought things through

EDIT: better still, put your comment inside an empty block

```
if (!something()) {
// Not worried if this fails because blah
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you could work with out parameters as well.

Comment: You don't know that; it depends what Jono's functions actually _do_ here (he's just provided an example snippet).

Comment: out and ref parameters are bad, very, very bad. AFAIR even Microsoft agreed that using out for things like Int32.TryParse() was not such a good idea. StyleCop and similar will also create a warning whenever you use out parameters. Anyways, this does not answer the question: -1